How can I programmatically change the color of the hamburger menu icon?
I'm trying to change the color of the hamburger menu icon in a mobile view using Velo in Wix. However, when I attempt to set the color using the following code:
$w.onReady(function () {
    $w("#menuToggle1").style.color = "red";
});

I receive the error: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'HiddenCollapsedElement'.
I understand that the style property is not applicable here.
What is the way to change the icon color of the menuToggle component programmatically?

It doesn't look like menu elements have a style property or have CSS support in Wix. So you can't actually change the color of the element at runtime.
You could hack the Wix environment (by using a CustomElement in Wix), but it is generally a bad idea.
As a workaround, you can duplicate your menu, change the color in the editor on the duplicate, and hide/show the menus accordingly.

This is a question about Wix elements. The elements do not expose all the properties of their underlying HTML elements. There are some hacky solutions to get to the underlying element, but they are not advisable as they are not guaranteed to continue to work if Wix changes how their system works.

Check the Wix documentation for the menu element. The example you point to is not a referring to a Wix environment. Like I said before, you can hack the Wix environment (by using a CustomElement in Wix), but it is generally a bad idea.
